# Tengo un error orphaned case y alguno que otro en que son del case

Tags: java, poo, switch, usecase

estoy trabajando en un proyecto escolar en el cual utilizo switch-case para las diferentes opciones en un trabajo, pero en el case 2 me marca el error ya mencionado, tengo un poco de desorden, quizá bastante, pero quisiera que me ayudarán en ese tipo de error, porfavor
También tengo otro error hasta el final del código que es por un case, más no logro entenderlo
Es bastante extenso el código, pero creen poder ayudarme, porfavor
También les comento que tengo otras clases secundarias en las que solo toma variables, no se si es importante, pero quería mencionarlo, tampoco se si aquí esta mal poner un código tan largo, perdón.

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Proyecto {
    

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean flag,flag1;
        File archivo;
         
         archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\\\OneDrive\\POO\\Proyecto.txt");
         
        try {
            if (archivo.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("Se a creado el archivo");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("No se a podido crear el archivo");
        }
        File miArchivo;
        FileWriter linea;
        PrintWriter escribir;
        String nombre="";
        String tecnico="";
        
        int numerot=0;
        flag1= true;
        do{
            
            int menu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, """
                                                                          Para balanceo presione 1
                                                                          Para tierras presione 2
                                                                          Para RXmer presione 3
                                                                          Para Seeker presione 4
                                                                          para SALIR presione 5""", "Menu de actividades preventivas ", 1));
            
        switch (menu){
            case 1 -> {
                do{
                    
                        flag= true;
                        String nm= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                                "nombre del tecnico");
                        int nt= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                        String T= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                        int integr= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "cuantos tecnicos participaron?","cantidad"));
                        String fch= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese la fecha",
                                "DD/MM/AA");
                        
                        Cuadrilla ccotm= new Cuadrilla(nm, nt, T,fch,integr);
                        ccotm.setNombre(nm.toUpperCase());
                        ccotm.setNoTecnico(nt);
                        ccotm.setTurno(T.toUpperCase());
                        
                        ccotm.setIntegrantes(integr);
                        ccotm.setFecha(fch);
                        
                        Empleado obj[]= new Empleado[integr];
                        miArchivo = new File("C:\\Users\\\\POO\\Proyecto.txt");
        if (!miArchivo.exists()){
            try {
                miArchivo.createNewFile();
                escribir = new PrintWriter(miArchivo,"utf-8");
                escribir.println("!Hola, bienvenidos a Izzi¡");
                nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnio encargado de la cuadrilla", "Ingresa el nombre del tecnico "+
                        "Solicitando datos"+3);
                int nut= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                String t= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                int fecha = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingresa  la fecha(DD/MM/AA) ",
                        "Solicitando datos",3));
                int inegr= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "cuantos tecnicos participaron?","cantidad"));
                tecnico=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingresa el numero del tecnico "+
                        "Solicitando datos"+3);
               
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            nombre= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                                    "nombre del tecnico");
                            nut= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                    "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                            t= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                            
                            obj[i]= new Empleado(nombre.toUpperCase(), nut, t);
                        }
                        int inc=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa la incidencia:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int nd=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa el nodo:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int inz=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa el interfaz:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        String sg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los segmentos");
                        int acti=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa los activos:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int acces=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa los accesorios:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        Balanceo bal=new Balanceo (0, 0, 0, "", 0, 0);
                        bal.seticidencia(inc);
                        bal.setnodo(nd);
                        bal.setinterfaz(inz);
                        bal.setsegmento(sg);
                        bal.setactivos(acti);
                        bal.setaccesorios(acces);
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha: "+ccotm.getFecha()+"\n"+
                                "\n incidencia: "+bal.geticidencia()+"\n Tecnico que alerta "+ccotm.getNombre()+
                                " no. de tecnico "+ccotm.getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"\n Nodo "+bal.getnodo()+" Interfaz "+ bal.getinterfaz()+" Segmento "+
                                bal.getsegmento()+"\n"+"\n Activos balanceados "+bal.getactivos()+" Accesorios requeridos "+bal.getaccesorios()+
                                " Turno "+ccotm.getTurno());
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tecnico de apoyo "+ obj[i].getNombre()
                                    +"\n"+"con numero de tecnico "+ obj[i].getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"del turno "+obj[i].getTurno());
                        }
                linea = new FileWriter(archivo,true);
                escribir = new PrintWriter(escribir);
                escribir.println(nombre);
                escribir.println(fecha);
                escribir.println(tecnico);
                linea.close();
                escribir.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Proyecto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else{
            try {
                escribir = new PrintWriter(miArchivo,"utf-8");
                escribir.println("!Hola, bienvenidos a Izzi¡");
                nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnio encargado de la cuadrilla", "Ingresa el nombre del tecnico "+
                        "Solicitando datos"+3);
                int nut= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                String t= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                int fecha = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingresa  la fecha(DD/MM/AA) ",
                        "Solicitando datos",3));
                int inegr= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "cuantos tecnicos participaron?","cantidad"));
                tecnico=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingresa el numero del tecnico "+
                        "Solicitando datos"+3);
               
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            nombre= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                                    "nombre del tecnico");
                            nut= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                    "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                            t= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                            
                            obj[i]= new Empleado(nombre.toUpperCase(), nut, t);
                        }
                        int inc=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa la incidencia:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int nd=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa el nodo:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int inz=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa el interfaz:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        String sg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los segmentos");
                        int acti=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa los activos:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int acces=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa los accesorios:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        Balanceo bal=new Balanceo (0, 0, 0, "", 0, 0);
                        bal.seticidencia(inc);
                        bal.setnodo(nd);
                        bal.setinterfaz(inz);
                        bal.setsegmento(sg);
                        bal.setactivos(acti);
                        bal.setaccesorios(acces);
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha: "+ccotm.getFecha()+"\n"+
                                "\n incidencia: "+bal.geticidencia()+"\n Tecnico que alerta "+ccotm.getNombre()+
                                " no. de tecnico "+ccotm.getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"\n Nodo "+bal.getnodo()+" Interfaz "+ bal.getinterfaz()+" Segmento "+
                                bal.getsegmento()+"\n"+"\n Activos balanceados "+bal.getactivos()+" Accesorios requeridos "+bal.getaccesorios()+
                                " Turno "+ccotm.getTurno());
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tecnico de apoyo "+ obj[i].getNombre()
                                    +"\n"+"con numero de tecnico "+ obj[i].getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"del turno "+obj[i].getTurno());
                        }
                linea = new FileWriter(archivo,true);
                escribir = new PrintWriter(escribir);
                escribir.println(nombre);
                escribir.println(fecha);
                escribir.println(tecnico);
                linea.close();
                escribir.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Proyecto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e) {
                
                       
                       
                }
                while (flag==false);
                }
                
            case 2 -> {
                do{
                    try {
                        flag= true;
                        String nm= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                                "nombre del tecnico");
                        int nt= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                        String T= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                        int integr= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "cuantos tecnicos participaron?","cantidad"));
                        String fch= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese la fecha",
                                "DD/MM/AA");
                        
                        Cuadrilla ccotm= new Cuadrilla(nm, nt, T,fch,integr);
                        ccotm.setNombre(nm.toUpperCase());
                        ccotm.setNoTecnico(nt);
                        ccotm.setTurno(T.toUpperCase());
                        
                        ccotm.setIntegrantes(integr);
                        ccotm.setFecha(fch);
                        
                        Empleado obj[]= new Empleado[integr];
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            nm= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                                    "nombre del tecnico");
                            nt= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                    "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                            T= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                            
                            obj[i]= new Empleado(nm.toUpperCase(), nt, T.toUpperCase());
                        }
                        int inc=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa las incidencias:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int nd=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa los nodos:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int inz=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa el interfaz:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        String sg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los segmentos");
                        int tt=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa el total de tierras:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        int mv=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null,"Ingresa los metros de varilla:","Solicitando datos",3));
                        Tierras tie=new Tierras(inc, nd, inz, sg, nd, nd);
                        tie.settotalTierra(tt);
                        tie.setmetrosDeVarilla(mv);
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fecha: "+ccotm.getFecha()+"\n"+
                                "\n incidencia: "+tie.geticidencia()+"\n Tecnico que alerta "+ccotm.getNombre()+
                                " no. de tecnico "+ccotm.getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"\n Nodo "+tie.getnodo()+" Interfaz "+ tie.getinterfaz()+" Segmento "+
                                tie.getsegmento()+"\n"+"\n Tierras instaladas "+tie.gettotalTierra()+" Metros de barilla "+tie.getmetrosDeVarilla()+
                                " Turno "+ccotm.getTurno());
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el tecnico "+ obj[i].getNombre()
                                    +"\n"+"con numero de tecnico "+ obj[i].getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"del turno "+obj[i].getTurno());
                        }
                        
                    }catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException error ){
                        flag =false;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INGRESE VALORE CORRECTOS PARA LOS CAMPOS DETERMINADOS\n "+
                                error.getMessage()
                                , "ERROR DE TIPO DE DATOS A LA ENTRADA ", 2);
                    }
                }while (flag==false);
                }
            case 3 -> {
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                do{
                    try {
                        flag= true;
                        String nm= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                                "nombre del tecnico");
                        int nt= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                        String T= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                        int integr= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "cuantos tecnicos participaron?","cantidad"));
                        String fch= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese la fecha",
                                "DD/MM/AA");
                        
                        Cuadrilla ccotm= new Cuadrilla(nm, nt, T,fch,integr);
                        ccotm.setNombre(nm.toUpperCase());
                        ccotm.setNoTecnico(nt);
                        ccotm.setTurno(T.toUpperCase());
                        
                        ccotm.setIntegrantes(integr);
                        ccotm.setFecha(fch);
                        
                        Empleado obj[]= new Empleado[integr];
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            nm= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                                    "nombre del tecnico");
                            nt= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                    "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                            T= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                            
                            obj[i]= new Empleado(nm.toUpperCase(), nt, T);
                        }
                        
                        int inc=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa las incidencias: ", "Solicitando datos",3));
                        int nd=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa los nodos: ", "Solicitando datos",3));
                        int inz=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa las interfaces: ", "Solicitando datos",3));
                        String sg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los segmentos");
                        String dñ=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los daños");
                        String mt=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los materiales");
                        
                        RxMer mer= new RxMer(inc, nd, inz, sg);
                        mer.setdaño(dñ);
                        mer.setmaterial(mt);
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha: "+ccotm.getFecha()+"\n"+
                                "\n incidencia: "+mer.getincidencia()+"\n Tecnico que alerta "+ccotm.getNombre()+
                                " no. de tecnico "+ccotm.getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"\n Nodo "+mer.getnodo()+" Interfaz "+ mer.getinterfaz()+" Segmento "+
                                mer.getsegmento()+"\n"+"\n Se reparo el daño  "+mer.getdaño()+" Empleando de materiales "+mer.getmaterial()+
                                " Turno "+ccotm.getTurno());
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tecnico de apollo "+ obj[i].getNombre()
                                    +"\n"+"con numero de tecnico "+ obj[i].getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"del turno "+obj[i].getTurno());
                        }
                        
                    }catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException error ){
                        flag =false;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INGRESE VALORE CORRECTOS PARA LOS CAMPOS DETERMINADOS\n "+
                                error.getMessage()
                                , "ERROR DE TIPO DE DATOS A LA ENTRADA ", 2);
                    }
                }while (flag==false);
                }
            case 4 -> {
                do{
                    try {
                        flag= true;
                        String nm= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                                "nombre del tecnico");
                        int nt= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                        String T= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                        int integr= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "cuantos tecnicos participaron?","cantidad"));
                        String fch= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese la fecha",
                                "DD/MM/AA");
                        
                        Cuadrilla ccotm= new Cuadrilla(nm, nt, T,fch,integr);
                        ccotm.setNombre(nm.toUpperCase());
                        ccotm.setNoTecnico(nt);
                        ccotm.setTurno(T.toUpperCase());
                        
                        ccotm.setIntegrantes(integr);
                        ccotm.setFecha(fch);
                        
                        Empleado obj[]= new Empleado[integr];
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            nm= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                                    "nombre del tecnico");
                            nt= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                    "ingresa el numero del esclavo ","8700000"));
                            T= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"pon el turno","M,V,N");
                            
                            obj[i]= new Empleado(nm.toUpperCase(), nt, T);
                        }
                        
                        int inc=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa las incidencias: ", "Solicitando datos",3));
                        int nd=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa los nodos: ", "Solicitando datos",3));
                        int inz=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa las interfaces: ", "Solicitando datos",3));
                        String sg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los segmentos");
                        int km=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa los kilometros recorridos: ", "Solicitando datos",3));
                        
                        Seeker seek= new Seeker(inc, nd, inz, sg, km);
                        seek.setKmrecorridos(km);
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha: "+ccotm.getFecha()+"\n"+
                                "\n incidencia: "+seek.getincidencia()+"\n Tecnico que alerta "+ccotm.getNombre()+
                                " no. de tecnico "+ccotm.getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"\n Nodo "+seek.getnodo()+" Interfaz "+ seek.getinterfaz()+" Segmento "+
                                seek.getsegmento()+"\n"+"\n km recorridos "+seek.getKmrecorridos()+
                                " Turno "+ccotm.getTurno());
                        
                        for(int i=0 ;i<integr ;i++){
                            
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tecnico de apollo "+ obj[i].getNombre()
                                    +"\n"+"con numero de tecnico "+ obj[i].getNoTecnico()+"\n"+"del turno "+obj[i].getTurno());
                        }
                        
                    }catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException error ){
                        flag =false;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INGRESE VALORE CORRECTOS PARA LOS CAMPOS DETERMINADOS\n "+
                                error.getMessage()
                                , "ERROR DE TIPO DE DATOS A LA ENTRADA ", 2);
                    }
                }while (flag==false);
                }
            case 5 -> {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gracias por emplear nuestros servivios ");
                System.exit(0);
                }
            default -> { 
                flag1= false;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INTRODUCE UNA OPCIONN VALIDA ....");
                }
        
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////7
                    
        }while(flag1== false);{
            
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   boolean flag, flag1;
   File archivo;

   archivo = new File( "C:\\Users\\\\OneDrive\\POO\\Proyecto.txt" );

   try {
      if( archivo.createNewFile() ) {
         System.out.println( "Se a creado el archivo" );
      }
   }
   catch( IOException e ) {
      System.err.println( "No se a podido crear el archivo" );
   }
   File miArchivo;
   FileWriter linea;
   PrintWriter escribir;
   String nombre = "";
   String tecnico = "";

   int numerot = 0;
   flag1 = true;
   do {
      int menu = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, """
                                                                    Para balanceo presione 1
                                                                    Para tierras presione 2
                                                                    Para RXmer presione 3
                                                                    Para Seeker presione 4
                                                                    para SALIR presione 5""", "Menu de actividades preventivas ", 1 ) );
      switch( menu ) {
         case 1:
            do {

               flag = true;
               String nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                       "nombre del tecnico" );
               int nt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                       "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
               String T = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );
               int integr = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                       "cuantos tecnicos participaron?", "cantidad" ) );
               String fch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "ingrese la fecha",
                       "DD/MM/AA" );

               Cuadrilla ccotm = new Cuadrilla( nm, nt, T, fch, integr );
               ccotm.setNombre( nm.toUpperCase() );
               ccotm.setNoTecnico( nt );
               ccotm.setTurno( T.toUpperCase() );

               ccotm.setIntegrantes( integr );
               ccotm.setFecha( fch );

               Empleado obj[] = new Empleado[ integr ];
               miArchivo = new File( "C:\\Users\\\\POO\\Proyecto.txt" );
               if( !miArchivo.exists() ) {
                  try {
                     miArchivo.createNewFile();
                     escribir = new PrintWriter( miArchivo, "utf-8" );
                     escribir.println( "!Hola, bienvenidos a Izzi¡" );
                     nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnio encargado de la cuadrilla", "Ingresa el nombre del tecnico "
                             + "Solicitando datos" + 3 );
                     int nut = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                             "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                     String t = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );
                     int fecha = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa  la fecha(DD/MM/AA) ",
                             "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int inegr = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                             "cuantos tecnicos participaron?", "cantidad" ) );
                     tecnico = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el numero del tecnico "
                             + "Solicitando datos" + 3 );

                     for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {
                        nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                                "nombre del tecnico" );
                        nut = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                        t = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );

                        obj[ i ] = new Empleado( nombre.toUpperCase(), nut, t );
                     }
                     int inc = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa la incidencia:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int nd = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el nodo:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int inz = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el interfaz:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     String sg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingrese los segmentos" );
                     int acti = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los activos:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int acces = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los accesorios:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     Balanceo bal = new Balanceo( 0, 0, 0, "", 0, 0 );
                     bal.seticidencia( inc );
                     bal.setnodo( nd );
                     bal.setinterfaz( inz );
                     bal.setsegmento( sg );
                     bal.setactivos( acti );
                     bal.setaccesorios( acces );

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Fecha: " + ccotm.getFecha() + "\n"
                             + "\n incidencia: " + bal.geticidencia() + "\n Tecnico que alerta " + ccotm.getNombre()
                             + " no. de tecnico " + ccotm.getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "\n Nodo " + bal.getnodo() + " Interfaz " + bal.getinterfaz() + " Segmento "
                             + bal.getsegmento() + "\n" + "\n Activos balanceados " + bal.getactivos() + " Accesorios requeridos " + bal.getaccesorios()
                             + " Turno " + ccotm.getTurno() );

                     for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Tecnico de apoyo " + obj[ i ].getNombre()
                                + "\n" + "con numero de tecnico " + obj[ i ].getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "del turno " + obj[ i ].getTurno() );
                     }
                     linea = new FileWriter( archivo, true );
                     escribir = new PrintWriter( escribir );
                     escribir.println( nombre );
                     escribir.println( fecha );
                     escribir.println( tecnico );
                     linea.close();
                     escribir.close();
                  }
                  catch( IOException ex ) {
                     Logger.getLogger( Proyecto.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
                  }
               }
               else {
                  try {
                     escribir = new PrintWriter( miArchivo, "utf-8" );
                     escribir.println( "!Hola, bienvenidos a Izzi¡" );
                     nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnio encargado de la cuadrilla", "Ingresa el nombre del tecnico "
                             + "Solicitando datos" + 3 );
                     int nut = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                             "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                     String t = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );
                     int fecha = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa  la fecha(DD/MM/AA) ",
                             "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int inegr = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                             "cuantos tecnicos participaron?", "cantidad" ) );
                     tecnico = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el numero del tecnico "
                             + "Solicitando datos" + 3 );

                     for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {
                        nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                                "nombre del tecnico" );
                        nut = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                                "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                        t = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );

                        obj[ i ] = new Empleado( nombre.toUpperCase(), nut, t );
                     }
                     int inc = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa la incidencia:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int nd = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el nodo:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int inz = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el interfaz:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     String sg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingrese los segmentos" );
                     int acti = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los activos:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     int acces = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los accesorios:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                     Balanceo bal = new Balanceo( 0, 0, 0, "", 0, 0 );
                     bal.seticidencia( inc );
                     bal.setnodo( nd );
                     bal.setinterfaz( inz );
                     bal.setsegmento( sg );
                     bal.setactivos( acti );
                     bal.setaccesorios( acces );

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Fecha: " + ccotm.getFecha() + "\n"
                             + "\n incidencia: " + bal.geticidencia() + "\n Tecnico que alerta " + ccotm.getNombre()
                             + " no. de tecnico " + ccotm.getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "\n Nodo " + bal.getnodo() + " Interfaz " + bal.getinterfaz() + " Segmento "
                             + bal.getsegmento() + "\n" + "\n Activos balanceados " + bal.getactivos() + " Accesorios requeridos " + bal.getaccesorios()
                             + " Turno " + ccotm.getTurno() );

                     for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Tecnico de apoyo " + obj[ i ].getNombre()
                                + "\n" + "con numero de tecnico " + obj[ i ].getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "del turno " + obj[ i ].getTurno() );
                     }
                     linea = new FileWriter( archivo, true );
                     escribir = new PrintWriter( escribir );
                     escribir.println( nombre );
                     escribir.println( fecha );
                     escribir.println( tecnico );
                     linea.close();
                     escribir.close();
                  }
                  catch( IOException ex ) {
                     Logger.getLogger( Proyecto.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
                  }
                  catch( HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e ) {

                  }
               }
            }
            while( flag == false );
            break;

         case 2:
            do {
               try {
                  flag = true;
                  String nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                          "nombre del tecnico" );
                  int nt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                          "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                  String T = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );
                  int integr = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                          "cuantos tecnicos participaron?", "cantidad" ) );
                  String fch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "ingrese la fecha",
                          "DD/MM/AA" );

                  Cuadrilla ccotm = new Cuadrilla( nm, nt, T, fch, integr );
                  ccotm.setNombre( nm.toUpperCase() );
                  ccotm.setNoTecnico( nt );
                  ccotm.setTurno( T.toUpperCase() );

                  ccotm.setIntegrantes( integr );
                  ccotm.setFecha( fch );

                  Empleado obj[] = new Empleado[ integr ];

                  for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {
                     nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                             "nombre del tecnico" );
                     nt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                             "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                     T = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );

                     obj[ i ] = new Empleado( nm.toUpperCase(), nt, T.toUpperCase() );
                  }
                  int inc = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa las incidencias:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  int nd = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los nodos:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  int inz = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el interfaz:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  String sg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingrese los segmentos" );
                  int tt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa el total de tierras:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  int mv = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los metros de varilla:", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  Tierras tie = new Tierras( inc, nd, inz, sg, nd, nd );
                  tie.settotalTierra( tt );
                  tie.setmetrosDeVarilla( mv );

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Fecha: " + ccotm.getFecha() + "\n"
                          + "\n incidencia: " + tie.geticidencia() + "\n Tecnico que alerta " + ccotm.getNombre()
                          + " no. de tecnico " + ccotm.getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "\n Nodo " + tie.getnodo() + " Interfaz " + tie.getinterfaz() + " Segmento "
                          + tie.getsegmento() + "\n" + "\n Tierras instaladas " + tie.gettotalTierra() + " Metros de barilla " + tie.getmetrosDeVarilla()
                          + " Turno " + ccotm.getTurno() );

                  for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "el tecnico " + obj[ i ].getNombre()
                             + "\n" + "con numero de tecnico " + obj[ i ].getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "del turno " + obj[ i ].getTurno() );
                  }

               }
               catch( HeadlessException | NumberFormatException error ) {
                  flag = false;
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "INGRESE VALORE CORRECTOS PARA LOS CAMPOS DETERMINADOS\n "
                          + error.getMessage(),
                          "ERROR DE TIPO DE DATOS A LA ENTRADA ", 2 );
               }
            }
            while( flag == false );
            break;
         case 3:
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            do {
               try {
                  flag = true;
                  String nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                          "nombre del tecnico" );
                  int nt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                          "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                  String T = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );
                  int integr = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                          "cuantos tecnicos participaron?", "cantidad" ) );
                  String fch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "ingrese la fecha",
                          "DD/MM/AA" );

                  Cuadrilla ccotm = new Cuadrilla( nm, nt, T, fch, integr );
                  ccotm.setNombre( nm.toUpperCase() );
                  ccotm.setNoTecnico( nt );
                  ccotm.setTurno( T.toUpperCase() );

                  ccotm.setIntegrantes( integr );
                  ccotm.setFecha( fch );

                  Empleado obj[] = new Empleado[ integr ];

                  for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {
                     nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                             "nombre del tecnico" );
                     nt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                             "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                     T = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );

                     obj[ i ] = new Empleado( nm.toUpperCase(), nt, T );
                  }

                  int inc = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa las incidencias: ", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  int nd = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los nodos: ", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  int inz = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa las interfaces: ", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  String sg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingrese los segmentos" );
                  String dñ = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingrese los daños" );
                  String mt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingrese los materiales" );

                  RxMer mer = new RxMer( inc, nd, inz, sg );
                  mer.setdaño( dñ );
                  mer.setmaterial( mt );

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Fecha: " + ccotm.getFecha() + "\n"
                          + "\n incidencia: " + mer.getincidencia() + "\n Tecnico que alerta " + ccotm.getNombre()
                          + " no. de tecnico " + ccotm.getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "\n Nodo " + mer.getnodo() + " Interfaz " + mer.getinterfaz() + " Segmento "
                          + mer.getsegmento() + "\n" + "\n Se reparo el daño  " + mer.getdaño() + " Empleando de materiales " + mer.getmaterial()
                          + " Turno " + ccotm.getTurno() );

                  for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Tecnico de apollo " + obj[ i ].getNombre()
                             + "\n" + "con numero de tecnico " + obj[ i ].getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "del turno " + obj[ i ].getTurno() );
                  }

               }
               catch( HeadlessException | NumberFormatException error ) {
                  flag = false;
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "INGRESE VALORE CORRECTOS PARA LOS CAMPOS DETERMINADOS\n "
                          + error.getMessage(),
                           "ERROR DE TIPO DE DATOS A LA ENTRADA ", 2 );
               }
            }
            while( flag == false );

         case 4:
            do {
               try {
                  flag = true;
                  String nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico encargado de la cuadrilla",
                          "nombre del tecnico" );
                  int nt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                          "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                  String T = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );
                  int integr = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                          "cuantos tecnicos participaron?", "cantidad" ) );
                  String fch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "ingrese la fecha",
                          "DD/MM/AA" );

                  Cuadrilla ccotm = new Cuadrilla( nm, nt, T, fch, integr );
                  ccotm.setNombre( nm.toUpperCase() );
                  ccotm.setNoTecnico( nt );
                  ccotm.setTurno( T.toUpperCase() );

                  ccotm.setIntegrantes( integr );
                  ccotm.setFecha( fch );

                  Empleado obj[] = new Empleado[ integr ];

                  for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {
                     nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Tecnico participante de la cuadrilla",
                             "nombre del tecnico" );
                     nt = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                             "ingresa el numero del esclavo ", "8700000" ) );
                     T = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "pon el turno", "M,V,N" );

                     obj[ i ] = new Empleado( nm.toUpperCase(), nt, T );
                  }

                  int inc = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa las incidencias: ", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  int nd = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los nodos: ", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  int inz = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa las interfaces: ", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );
                  String sg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingrese los segmentos" );
                  int km = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Ingresa los kilometros recorridos: ", "Solicitando datos", 3 ) );

                  Seeker seek = new Seeker( inc, nd, inz, sg, km );
                  seek.setKmrecorridos( km );

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Fecha: " + ccotm.getFecha() + "\n"
                          + "\n incidencia: " + seek.getincidencia() + "\n Tecnico que alerta " + ccotm.getNombre()
                          + " no. de tecnico " + ccotm.getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "\n Nodo " + seek.getnodo() + " Interfaz " + seek.getinterfaz() + " Segmento "
                          + seek.getsegmento() + "\n" + "\n km recorridos " + seek.getKmrecorridos()
                          + " Turno " + ccotm.getTurno() );

                  for( int i = 0; i < integr; i++ ) {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Tecnico de apollo " + obj[ i ].getNombre()
                             + "\n" + "con numero de tecnico " + obj[ i ].getNoTecnico() + "\n" + "del turno " + obj[ i ].getTurno() );
                  }

               }
               catch( HeadlessException | NumberFormatException error ) {
                  flag = false;
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "INGRESE VALORE CORRECTOS PARA LOS CAMPOS DETERMINADOS\n "
                          + error.getMessage(),
                           "ERROR DE TIPO DE DATOS A LA ENTRADA ", 2 );
               }
            }
            while( flag == false );
            break;
         case 5:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Gracias por emplear nuestros servivios " );
            System.exit( 0 );
            break;
         default:
            flag1 = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "INTRODUCE UNA OPCIONN VALIDA ...." );
      }
   }
   while( flag1 == false );
}
```

Acá te dejo el código corregido, basicamente tenías dos tipos de problemas, uno, para usar **case 1 -> {**, debes tener al menos "12" **case**, ese error no te lo marcaba, porque primero encontraba el **case orphane** que se producía, por un serio problema con los cierres de "llaves", esto a su vez, probablemente sea provocado por el gran tamaño de la función, y la falta de un mecanismo de prevención, como puede ser que cada vez que abrís una llave, generas la de cierre.

Comment: ¡Te lo agradezco muchísimo Marce! Tratare de mejorar mis códigos, gracias de verdad

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!.